# How To use SdWebImage for images if they are in the form of Data?

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am New to iphone Development. Using SdwebImage is fine, when the image is available in the form of url. But When Coming to Images Which are in the form of data, I unable to use this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

you have to convert `NSData` to`NSString` and after this you must convert to `NSString` in to `NSURL` then use it in `SDWebImage` like:-

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
```